# Как правильно отрендерить объекты вокруг камеры?

Tags: java, opengl, 3d, render, lwjgl

Добрый день.
Впервые занимаюсь созданием 3д пространства при помощи lwjgl на java. Столкнулся с такой вот проблемой: 
У меня есть 2 куба, первым рендерится синий, вторым красный. В игре все выглядит так, что последний рендерящийся объект(красный) виден сквозь все.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
 Как возможно решить эту проблему?

```
                blue.draw();
                glTranslatef(100, 200, -100);
                red.draw();
```

Comment: Включите буфер глубины (glDepthTest)